# SIGSEGV when using threads with Bullet 2.87 under Linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads, bullet

So, here is my problem.
I have some code to create a thread and update a `btDynamicWorld` constantly. Under Windows it just works fine BUT under Linux, it crash when updating the dynamic world.

Here is the block of code which creates and launch the thread :

```cpp
void EXP_Game::StartPhysicsEngineThread() {
    std::thread phys_thread([](EXP_Game* game) {
        RD_FrameLimiter* lmt = new RD_FrameLimiter(60);

        std::cout << "Started Physics Engine thread" << std::endl;
        while (!game->GetRenderer()->WantToClose()) {
            lmt->start();

            game->GetMainMutex()->lock();
            game->UpdatePhysics(); //<-------------- Crash happen here
            game->GetMainMutex()->unlock();

            lmt->stop();
            lmt->WaitAll();
        }

        delete lmt;

    }, this);

    phys_thread.detach();
}
```

And there is the function `UpdatePhysics()` :

```cpp
void EXP_Game::UpdatePhysics() {
    if(m_physicsHandler)
        m_physicsHandler->UpdateWorld();
}
```

I put here the content of the function `UpdateWorld()` :

```cpp
void EXP_PhysicsHandler::UpdateWorld() {
    if(m_dWorld != nullptr)
        m_dWorld->stepSimulation(m_updtTime, 10);
}
```

And finally, I paste here the backtrace

```
#0  0x00007ffff7fa7c59 in EXP_PhysicsHandler::UpdateWorld (this=0x555555aaf070) at /home/mathis/Bureau/Dev/ExpansionGameEngine/src/ExpansionGameEngineCore/EXP_PhysicsHandler.cpp:38
#1  0x00007ffff7f98fc3 in EXP_Game::UpdatePhysics (this=0x55555556c320) at /home/mathis/Bureau/Dev/ExpansionGameEngine/src/ExpansionGameEngineCore/EXP_Game.cpp:445
#2  0x00007ffff7f97fc5 in EXP_Game::<lambda(EXP_Game*)>::operator()(EXP_Game *) const (__closure=0x555555ad1a28, game=0x55555556c320) at /home/mathis/Bureau/Dev/ExpansionGameEngine/src/ExpansionGameEngineCore/EXP_Game.cpp:297
#3  0x00007ffff7f9b867 in std::__invoke_impl<void, EXP_Game::StartPhysicsEngineThread()::<lambda(EXP_Game*)>, EXP_Game*>(std::__invoke_other, EXP_Game::<lambda(EXP_Game*)> &&, EXP_Game *&&) (__f=..., 
    __args#0=@0x555555ad1a28: 0x55555556c320) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/invoke.h:60
#4  0x00007ffff7f9b3e0 in std::__invoke<EXP_Game::StartPhysicsEngineThread()::<lambda(EXP_Game*)>, EXP_Game*>(EXP_Game::<lambda(EXP_Game*)> &&, EXP_Game *&&) (__fn=..., __args#0=@0x555555ad1a28: 0x55555556c320)
    at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/invoke.h:95
#5  0x00007ffff7f9b069 in std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<EXP_Game::StartPhysicsEngineThread()::<lambda(EXP_Game*)>, EXP_Game*> >::_M_invoke<0, 1>(std::_Index_tuple<0, 1>) (this=0x555555ad1a28) at /usr/include/c++/9/thread:244
#6  0x00007ffff7f9aec2 in std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<EXP_Game::StartPhysicsEngineThread()::<lambda(EXP_Game*)>, EXP_Game*> >::operator()(void) (this=0x555555ad1a28) at /usr/include/c++/9/thread:251
#7  0x00007ffff7f9ae2a in std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<EXP_Game::StartPhysicsEngineThread()::<lambda(EXP_Game*)>, EXP_Game*> > >::_M_run(void) (this=0x555555ad1a20) at /usr/include/c++/9/thread:195
#8  0x00007ffff7d75f74 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x00007ffff744a669 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:479
#10 0x00007ffff7bb6323 in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95
```

For threads under Linux I use `libpthread`.

What is potentially wrong with this code ? What could be the reason of these crashes ?

Note : There is two other threads running with other libs on the same pattern but they are running like a charm.

Note 2 : When I don't update the dynamic world it works.

Comment: The list of "potentially wrong" things is unlimited, however the shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: A [mcve] would be good. Going purely by your code snippets; I see no synchronization of access to shared variables, that just *screams* data race and [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Answer (score 0):

To find data races if any I would recommend to build your project (including Bullet engine itself) with a [thread sanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html) enabled. This tool is available in both GCC and Clang modern versions.

Comment: Oh great I'll try that